# Removing white space around scatter3D plot

Tags: r, scatter3d

From the following code

```
D<-matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
layout(matrix(c(1,2),ncol=1), widths=c(4,1), heights=1.2)
scatter3D(D[,1],D[,2],D[,3],colkey = FALSE)
plot(D[,1],type="l")
```

I get the following plot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRDGm.png). I would like that the scatter3D plot completely fits the layout portion assigned to it. How may I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem as follows,

```
D<-matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
layout(matrix(c(1,2),ncol=1), widths=c(4,1), heights=1.2)
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
scatter3D(D[,1],D[,2],D[,3],colkey = FALSE)
par(mar=  c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(D[,1],type="l")
```